Reference a sheet with today's date as the name
I currently have a Google sheet with an apps script and timer that generates a new sheet once a day, with today's date as the name.  The new sheet is automatically named "11/1/2024", tomorrow's sheet is automatically named "11/2/2024", etc.  Using IMPORTRANGE, I want to import the data into a separate sheet file.  But I only want it to import information from the most current sheet in the first file, the one with today's date.
The way I currently have the IMPORTRANGE formula set up, it is referencing a specific sheet name, i.e. =IMPORTRANGE("link","11/1/2024!A1:A50").  This works great for a day, but I want to implement a formula that will dynamically update each day to source the sheet with that day's date.  I've tried implementing TODAY instead of the sheet name into the IMPORTRANGE formula, but it doesn't work.
Any assistance is appreciated, thanks in advance.
Edit: pgSystemTester did a wonderful job showing me a formula that worked for this situation, please see below.  In Spreadsheet 1 I had to create a master sheet, which would reference the sheet with today's date and reflect that data.  In Spreadsheet 2, a separate file, I could then use IMPORTRANGE to import the data from the master sheet in Spreadsheet 1.  The master sheet in spreadsheet 1 was always updating to reflect the data of the sheet with today's date, and Spreadsheet 2 would import that updated data.
After more research I found another formula that works as well and eliminates a step.  For anyone struggling with the same issue, this is the formula to import data from one google sheet to another citing the sheet with today's date as the title Using IMPORTRANGE:
=IMPORTRANGE("YOUR_SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_URL", TEXT(TODAY(), "MM/dd/yyyy") & "!A1:B10")

Please read the tag descriptions before using them. The reference and auto-update tags you use do not mean what you think they do, and are not suitable for use on the question you asked. Tags have specific meanings here, and they have relevance and meaning for searches and getting questions directed to users. Please try to use them properly in the future.

@Ken White Roger that Ken, thanks for taking the time to point me in the right direction!

Depending on the date format you can use INDIRECT with TODAY and Text. This works for me...
=indirect("'"&text(today(),"MM/DD/YYYY")&"'!A5")
Link to a sample sheet


Thank you so much for taking the time to show me this!!  I tried this and it is working very well if I set up a "master" in the sheet with the data.  The master references the sheet with today's date, and then the separate file imports that data using IMPORTRANGE and referencing the master.  One question, is there a way to work the INDIRECT formula into the IMPORTRANGE formula so as to remove the extra step of having a master sheet?

Glad it works. Could you please click accept before asking for more help?

Sure!  My pleasure.  Is it possible to integrate those 2 formulas?

Honestly I'm not sure what your'e doing, but you can certainly have a range of values as part of a formula. Your first question was much clearer, sorry.

Thanks for all your help I really appreciate it!
